# How to compare equality of memory representation of numpy arrays (e.g. including dtype)

Tags: python, numpy

How can I compare whether two numpy arrays are *exactly* identical in memory, so that e.g.

```
np.array([0,1]) == np.array([0,1])
```

is True, but

```
np.array([0,1]) == np.array([[0,1]])
np.array([0,1], dtype=np.int32) == np.array([0,1], dtype=np.int64)
```

are both False. `np.array_equal` doesn't have a `compare_dtypes` option. I guess there might be other ways for the memory representation of an array to differ too (e.g. endian-ness)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itemsize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemsize.html) to compare them in terms of their length in bytes:

```
a1 = np.array([0,1], dtype=np.int32)
a2 = np.array([0,1], dtype=np.int64)
a1.itemsize == a2.itemsize
# False
```

---

If you want to compare both their size and content you could examine the raw contents of data memory with [`ndarray.tobytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html):

```
a1.tobytes() == a2.tobytes()
# False
```

Comment: But that doesn't compare contents?

Comment: So yo mean exactly identical in content and memory?

Comment: Yep - identical in all respects

Comment: Updating @user2667066

Comment: I guess I could serialize using e.g. `pickle.dumps` and compare those versions. A bit hacky though. Surely there's something built-in?

Comment: Comparing bytes wouldn't work for same byte-size representations, e.g. uint32 and int32 arrays would look identical, but I would want this to be False. (i.e. I want to compare all aspects of the arrays, including dtype, and anything else stored by numpy)

Comment: You're right they would look identical... Not sure if there is a direct way of doing this, other than comparing each aspect individually, i.e datatype and content @user2667066

Comment: @user2667066 give a look at `np.core.records.fromarrays`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which aspects you want to cover the minimum would be comparing `x.dtype` (this includes endianness) `x.shape` and `x.strides`.

You may also want to look at some flags. For example, `x.flags.aligned` may be considered part of the memory layout in a broad sense as may be `x.flags.writeable` (and perhaps `x.flags.owndata`).

The `C/F_CONTIGUOUS` flags, on the other hand, are redundant once you know shape and strides, and finally, there are `UPDATEIFCOPY` and `WRITEBACKIFCOPY` which I don't understand well enough to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using `pickle.dumps`:

```
import pickle
a1 = np.array([0,1], dtype=np.int32)
a2 = np.array([0,1], dtype=np.int64)
pickle.dumps(a1) == pickle.dumps(a2)
```

But it seems a bit of a hack.